# MIME type ('text/html') not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled in Django Web Application

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, django

I am hosting a Django web application on a cPanel web hosting server. I have the application up and running however it is not applying the CSS stylesheets to my `index.html` template or my `admin` console. I receive the following error `Refused to apply style from 'https://website/staticfiles/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

I ran the `collectstatic` command and the admin CSS files and my CSS files are inside the `staticfiles` directory. I am not sure what else I can do to fix this issue, the media files are rendering correctly I am only having issues with the static CSS files.

```
settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

```
urls.py

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('SocialLinks.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Directory structure is as follows

```
home
├─ userName
|  ├── myapp       
│  |    └── static
|  |    |   |-css
|  |    |   |  |-style.css
|  |    |__ staticfiles
|  |         |-css
|  |         |  |-style.css
|  |         |-admin
|  |         |  |-css
|  |         |    |-style.css
|  ├── templates
```

Comment: How are you serving your static files? Using the `static` view in production is not recommended but you seem to only have it handling your media files?

Comment: It is handling user-uploaded images which are displaying correctly. User-uploaded images are uploaded to the `media` directory. Its the `static` files that are not displaying. They are hosted in the `staticfiles` directory whenever I run `collectstatic`